# required_if in validation package don't work in validation of parent struct from nested (only work in same level)

Tags: validation, go

1. if comment `IRN {IRN:1}` we have validation error.
2. but if comment `Day {Day:"01"}` in nested `json` we don't have validation error.

```
import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
)

type A struct {
    CardType int `validate:"required"`

    IRN uint8 `validate:"required_if=CardType 1,omitempty"`
    B   B     `validate:"required"`
}

type B struct {
    Day string `validate:"required_if=A.CardType 1"`
}

func Test(t *testing.T) {

    m := A{
        CardType: 1,
        IRN:      1, //  
        B: B{
            Day: "01", // 
        },
    }

    validate := validator.New()
    err := validate.Struct(m)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it fits to your case, you can simply move validation to the parent struct :

```
type A struct {
    CardType int `validate:"required"`

    IRN uint8 `validate:"required_if=CardType 1,omitempty"`
    B   B     `validate:"required_if=CardType 1"`
}

type B struct {
    Day string `validate:"required"`
}

func Test_validator(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("error when IRN=1 and B is not set", func(t *testing.T) {
        m := A{
            CardType: 1,
            IRN:      1,
            B:        B{
                //Day: "01",
            },
        }
        v := validator.New()
        err := v.Struct(m)
        assert.Error(t, err)
    })
}
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://go.dev/play/p/Qigi_9D5qPs)</kbd>

or define custom validation function:

```
func myValidate(sl validator.StructLevel) {
    if a, ok := sl.Current().Interface().(A); ok {
        if a.CardType == 1 && a.B.Day != "01" {
            sl.ReportError(sl.Current().Interface(), "Day", "A.B.Day", "", "")
        }
    }
}

func Test_validator(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("error when IRN=1 and B is not set", func(t *testing.T) {
        m := A{
            CardType: 1,
            IRN:      1,
            B:        B{
                //Day: "01",
            },
        }
        v := validator.New()
        v.RegisterStructValidation(myValidate, A{}) //  register "myValidate"
        err := v.Struct(m)
        assert.Error(t, err)
    })
}
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://go.dev/play/p/SHyTiHz98i2)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by kozmo is right one but I was still struggling with calling my custom required_if validator because I was missing third parameter in validator.RegisterValidation func, due to which my custom validation was not triggering at all when field value was nil  / not present, here is how i resolved it:

```
var customRequiredIf validator.Func = func(fl validator.FieldLevel) bool {
// inside custom required if, now you can use your logic to check if this field is required or not
....}


validate := validator.New()
validate.RegisterValidation("custom_required_if", customRequiredIf, true)


 type Mystruct struct{
   Test *bool `validate:"custom_required_if"`
 }

 myst := Mystruct{}
 validate.ValidateStruct(myst)

 err := validate.Struct(s)
 if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Err(s):\n%+v\n", err)
 }
```

In go validator below is declaration of Register validation:

```
func (v *Validate) RegisterValidation(tag string, fn Func, callValidationEvenIfNull ...bool) error {
    return v.RegisterValidationCtx(tag, wrapFunc(fn), callValidationEvenIfNull...)
}
```

Third parameter is callValidationEvenIfNull bool is to trigger validation even when value is null or nil.