# Validate inner field based on outer field

Tags: go, validation

I want to validate the following struct

```
type Outer struct {
    Field1 string `validate:"required"`
    Field2 string `validate:"required_if=Field1 1"`
    Inner  Inner  `validate:"required_if=Field1 1"`
}

type Inner struct {
    Field3 string `validate:"required"`
}
```

I also made a [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/aBrGZq6VTwZ) to try and test this.
I want Field3 to not validate when the condition `"required_if=Field1 1"` in Inner field is not met.

I also tried a solution proposed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74170426/required-if-in-validation-package-dont-work-in-validation-of-parent-struct-from) but It alway return success no matter what

```
type Outer struct {
    Field1 string `validate:"required"`
    Field2 string `validate:"required_if=Field1 1"`
    Inner  Inner  `validate:"required_if=Field1 1"`
}

type Inner struct {
    Field3 string `validate:"required_if=Outer.Field1 1"`
}
```

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/zauPR33FmES)
What would be the best approach to solve this problem?
Also it would be neat if there is a cleaner way to require multiple value of Field1 instead of the following

```
Field2 string `validate:"required_if=Field1 1 Field1 2"`
```