# go-playground/validator required_if based on parent struct field

Tags: go

The required_if tag is not working when using a nested struct. I want to validate fields which are part of nested struct to be validated if the parent struct field is true.

Can anyone tell me why required_if is not working here? It works if the fields are of same struct.

Is this a limitation? I am not able to find anything in the doc related to it. or is there any other way we can achieve it?

I tried making the F1Config as pointer but still it did not work. This will not work on playground as expected because the validator package is big.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
)

type Config struct {
    ToggleFeatureOne bool
    FeatureOneConfig F1Config `validate:"required_if=ToggleFeatureOne true"`
}

type F1Config struct {
    Host     string `validate:"required_if=ToggleFeatureOne true"`
    Port     string `validate:"required_if=ToggleFeatureOne true"`
    SomeBool bool
}

var validate *validator.Validate

func main() {

    validate = validator.New(validator.WithRequiredStructEnabled())

    c := Config{
        ToggleFeatureOne: true,
        FeatureOneConfig: F1Config{
            Host:     "",
            Port:     "",
            SomeBool: true,
        },
    }

    err := validate.Struct(c)
    if err != nil {
        if _, ok := err.(*validator.InvalidValidationError); ok {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        for _, err := range err.(validator.ValidationErrors) {

            fmt.Println(err.Namespace())
            fmt.Println(err.Field())
            fmt.Println(err.StructNamespace())
            fmt.Println(err.StructField())
            fmt.Println(err.Tag())
            fmt.Println(err.ActualTag())
            fmt.Println(err.Kind())
            fmt.Println(err.Type())
            fmt.Println(err.Value())
            fmt.Println(err.Param())
            fmt.Println()
        }

        // from here you can create your own error messages in whatever language you wish
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [required\_if in validation package don't work in validation of parent struct from nested (only work in same level)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74170426/required-if-in-validation-package-dont-work-in-validation-of-parent-struct-from)